# Magento Community Edition upgrade to Enterprise

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.9, upgrade

i'm new in the magento world, and now i'm starting to create my first e-commerce with the Community Edition.

But i want to ask you if in the future i want  to upgrade the Community edition with the Enterprise Edition, is possible? if yes it's a complicate process?

regards

Alberto

Comment: You may be interested to watch [this](http://de.meet-magento.com/2014/07/harsh-truth-magento-enterprise/?lang=en) presentation from a meet magento earlier this year before you consider upgrading to EE.

Comment: We treat a EE upgrade the same as a CE upgrade and I have done this many times. As Marius said there are issues that need to be covered in modules and themes, but this is the same for any upgrade.

Comment: You really need to be running $multi-million revenue/yr to justify it, and then once you reach there you probably want to look towards a migration rather than an upgrade as the surrounding architecture will change including business processes, extensions, and custom scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory is possible. I've done it before.  (CE 1.1 -> EE 1.9)
The problems may appear on third party extensions. Some of them may be compatible with CE and not compatible with EE.
I guess you will have to test them manually.
As for the upgrade...I did it this way.
I installed EE over the database I had from the CE version.
Everything went smoothly.
An other problem I had, was the password hashing.
EE uses a different hashing method. `sha1` if I remember correctly.
But you can change the encryption model in EE and make it use the one from CE so you can keep the old passwords.